# Flask server does not recognize my own imported module (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, flask, heroku

In my main Python file, I import another script of mine called `helper_1.py` (from the subfolder `my_helpers`) like this:

```
from my_helpers.helper_1 as h1
```

However, when I now try to start my server (or deploy it to Heroku), the server will crash with the error notice:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_helpers'
```

I do have a Procfile, requirements.txt, runtime.txt, and wsgi.py.

The content of my wsgi.py is:

```
from app.main import app
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

**MY QUESTION:**
Where and how do I have to declare my custom modules (own scripts) so they are properly detected when starting the Flask server?

*Everything works fine if I leave out the external reference to my custom module.*

Comment: Does `my_helpers` have an `__init__.py` in it? If not, put one there, without any contents.

Comment: Run this before start server: `export PYTHONPATH=.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder my_helpers needs to be a package. To do this put an `__init__.py` file inside the `my_helpers` folder. This maybe fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, that actually did. Thank you. And interestingly it worked even with the file being completely empty.